# How do i delete the previous messages that my discord bot sent in a specific channel?

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, chatbot

I'm trying to make a discord bot that sends a message in a specific channel for telling users when my Minecraft server is on or off. I just need to send 2 embeds one for starting and another for turning off
like this:

[image]

I'm trying to delete the old messages the bot has sent but I don't know how.

```py
import discord
import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
Ntime = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
txtStart = ()
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    channel = client.get_channel(800317242910834699)
    embed= discord.Embed(title="[ Server Status ]", description="Running...", color=discord.Color.green())
    embed.add_field(name="success At :", value=Ntime, inline=True)
    file = discord.File(os.path.join("D:\Scripts\Discord/ServerStarted.gif"), filename="ServerStarted.gif")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://ServerStarted.gif")
    message = await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)

    embed= discord.Embed(title="[ Server Status ]", description="shutting down...", color=discord.Color.red())
    embed.add_field(name="success At :", value=Ntime, inline=True)
    file = discord.File(os.path.join("D:\Scripts\Discord/ServerStoped.gif"), filename="ServerStoped.gif")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://ServerStoped.gif")
    await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TextChannel.purge` method:

```py
await channel.purge(limit=1)
```

Remember to send the message *afterwards*, not *beforehand*.

Note that this method will delete the **oldest** message in the channel, if you want to delete the latest message sent by the bot you can use use a check function:

```py
def is_me(m):
    return m.author == client.user

await channel.purge(limit=1, check=is_me)
```

#### Reference:

- [`TextChannel.purge`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.purge)

Comment: Alright, remember to accept the answer if it helped